# Limit maximum incoming connections per IP

Tags: networking, server, firewall

I have a server with some code, and for x parallel connections/requests that one IP sends, the server runs x parallel threads (so it runs the code x times in parallel). To put a limit to the currently opened threads by a single IP, I want to configure my csf firewall to make it accept a maximum of x parallel connections for each IP.

Note: I've seen solutions that let you set a maximum number of IPs that can connect to the server, or a maximum number of total connections, but it's different from what i want.

Comment: This likely works https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139285/limit-max-connections-per-ip-address-and-new-connections-per-second-with-iptable#:~:text=https%3A//unix.stackexchange.com/a/143715/10017

Comment: Hello, that works for ports and not for IPs unfortunately. How can I configure MAX X IP?